# Show only outermost line of Radar Chart

Tags: mpandroidchart, radar-chart

I have issue i'm using MpChart to show radar chart.
[The chart render by Mpchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFHR4.png)

Now, I want to show outermost line same
[The chart i want to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6xpQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

i have found solution. I override RadarRenderer class, fun drawExtra

```
 for (int j = 0; j < labelCount; j++) {
        if (j < labelCount - 1) continue;
        for (int i = 0; i < mChart.getData().getEntryCount(); i++) {

            float r = (mChart.getYAxis().mEntries[j] - mChart.getYChartMin()) * factor;

            Utils.getPosition(center, r, sliceangle * i + rotationangle, p1out);
            Utils.getPosition(center, r, sliceangle * (i + 1) + rotationangle, p2out);

            c.drawLine(p1out.x, p1out.y, p2out.x, p2out.y, mWebPaint);


        }
    }
```